# NSolve giving results very slowly

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I have the following function :

```
paramFinal = {σ -> 0.35, ρ -> 0.85, h -> 60, a -> 1, b -> 0.1, δ -> 0.001, γ -> 0.0001, ψ -> 60, θ -> 0.09586401037966653};

adap[β_, root22_] := (1 - root22) root22 - (γ a ((ψ a θ γ b  (\σ (1 - Exp[-(β - ρ) h]))/(β - ρ))/(root22 ((ρ + θ) - (1 - 2 root22)) ((a - δ) - (ρ + θ))))^(-1/\σ))/(a - δ) /. paramFinal
```

I try to make a list of variables root22 and $\beta$ and I write

```
solK[i_] := NSolve[adap[β, i] == 0 /. paramFinal, {β}, Reals];
Table[solK[i], {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]
```

There are some error messages as well but this operation gives result very very slowly. 
What can I do to make the procedure faster ?

Comment: I can run the code above in 2 sec and it gives some results with no errors.

Comment: @happyfish I am using Mathematica 9.0 and have the results very slowly. Interesting...

Comment: I am using v11.1. The output is `{{{\[Beta] -> 1.13078}}, {{\[Beta] -> 0.92142}}, {{\[Beta] -> 
    0.876976}}, {{\[Beta] -> 0.855107}}, {{\[Beta] -> 
    0.840542}}, {{\[Beta] -> 0.82927}}, {{\[Beta] -> 
    0.819591}}, {{\[Beta] -> 0.810363}}, {{\[Beta] -> 0.799883}}, {}}`

Comment: Version 10.0.0 is slow and gives the error `NSolve::ratnz:`.

Comment: If `NSolve::ratnz:` is the error that you get, you should replace 0.35 with 35/100 and so on.

Comment: @mattiav27 yes thanks for that. I don't get anymore this error. I ran the code on Mathematica 11. It works fine but I am surprised anyway that it rans to slowly on Mathematica 9 because it is not that a complicated calculation I guess.

Comment: @happyfish thanks for the help !

Comment: The unknown appears both inside a transcendental function and in an "algebraic position" outside the function.  That makes it seem like a complicated calculation.

Answer (score 1):

**`NSolve[]`.**
It often helps in transcendental equations to bound the unknowns, if bounds can be determined.  This might be done by plotting.

```
solK[i_] := NSolve[adap[β, i] == 0 && 0.1 < β < 1.5 /. paramFinal, {β}, Reals];
Table[solK[i], {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>
>   ...
>   General::stop: Further output of Solve::ratnz will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

```
(*
  {{{β -> 1.13078}},  {{β -> 0.92142}}, {{β -> 0.876976}}, {{β -> 0.855107}}, 
   {{β -> 0.840542}}, {{β -> 0.82927}}, {{β -> 0.819591}}, {{β -> 0.810363}},
   {{β -> 0.799883}}, {}}
*)
```

Reasonably fast:

```
Quiet@Table[solK[i], {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.151135, Null}  *)
```

**`FindRoot[]`.**
Plots of the function suggest it is monotonic, in which case `FindRoot` is probably a better alternative; however, it fails on the last equation because there is no root.

```
solK[i_] := FindRoot[adap[β, i] == 0 /. paramFinal, {β, 1}];
Table[solK[i], {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]
```

> FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

```
(*
  {{β -> 1.13078}, {β -> 0.92142}, {β -> 0.876976}, {β -> 0.855107}, {β -> 0.840542},
   {β -> 0.82927}, {β -> 0.819591}, {β -> 0.810363}, {β -> 0.799883},
   {β -> 0.236409}}  <-- not a solution
*)
```

Ten times faster, though:

```
Quiet@Table[solK[i], {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.015183, Null}  *)
```